# Change of plans, can I still use the visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

My business trip was canceled in Austria, can I use the multi entry visa to travel somewhere else in the schengen zone?

Answer (score 3):

**I wouldn't risk it**, the primary purpose of your trip no longer holds true and you haven't even used the visa once for it. If you use the same visa for the first time for tourism you will definitely be questioned as to why, and possible be refused entry.

Had you first utilized the visa for the stated purpose it would have been perfectly alright to have subsequent touristic visits but the very first one for a different purpose, when the primary justification no longer holds true, sounds tough, **though it isn't forbidden**.